# Simplifying as an exact value (Simplest Radical Form)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey, I have a problem: solve for exact value (simplest radical form) $-3\sqrt{27}$ , the result is $-9 \sqrt3$ . I'm in 8th grade studying for a Math placement test to take trigonometry as a freshman next year. This doesn't seem to be covered in my textbook. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you are familiar with [the rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties) that (for positive $a$ and $b$)
$$\sqrt{a\times b}=\sqrt{a}\,\,\times\sqrt{b}$$
Can you see how to break up 27 into $a\times b$ for the right $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I believe so. It's my understanding that you use factors with the product of $a \times b$ and ideally picking a set with at least one perfect square.

Comment: @Anthony K: Exactly right! There is in fact such an ideal pair of factors for 27. Do you know which numbers go into 27?

Comment: Oh my Darwin. I can't believe I forgot this! I get it now! Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony K: no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to emphasize a different aspect of this question. If you punch both quantities into a calculator you'll get the same number, $$-15.588457\ldots$$
This is the "real" meaning of the equation at hand, $$ -3\sqrt{27} = -9\sqrt{3}.$$
The manipulation suggested by Zev leads you to a proof of this equality, but you should understand what it means: both expressions have the same value.

Therefore, I suggest you not only familiarize yourself with the identity $$\sqrt{a\times b} = \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b},$$ but also try to understand *why* it's true. Please don't think of it as a *rule* but as an intuitively obvious *property* of numbers. Of course, you can only move from the former interpretation to the latter once you've internalized the meaning of and reason behind this formula.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with the first assertion.  Equality is much, much deeper than 'evaluating these on the calculator gives the same result', and even in 8th grade I think it's worth explaining (as you say) the _why_ of the equation, far beyond 'they're numerically the same'.

Comment: I was worried about the "mindless manipulation" aspect of the question, especially because of Zev's choice of the term *rule*.

Comment: I agree with Yuval, "property" might be a better choice of words than "rule".